# Make bootable disk from tar archive

Tags: linux, boot, grub2, tar, suse

I have a compressed tar archive from a SLES 11 root directory. I'd like to boot another machine with a live linux, extract my OS archive on a disk, and make the disk bootable. Is there any easy way to do that?

I tried to boot from a live DVD, then extracted the image onto a disk and then tried to run:

`grub2-install --recheck --boot-directory=/mount/boot/ /dev/sda`

But when I issued:

`grub2-mkconfig -o /mount/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

I get this error:

/usr/sbin/grub2-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `tmpfs'.

Btw, the number of disks and their size may be different between the original and the target machines.